# delete all current cells from datagridview

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

can anyone help me to make the following code to delete all the "highlighted" cells(current cells)  contents in my datagridview? it always deletes the content of the last selected cell only

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.KeyDown
    If e.KeyData = Keys.Delete Then

        For Each cell In DataGridView1.SelectedCells
            DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = ""
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.KeyDown
    If e.KeyData = Keys.Delete Then

        For Each cell In DataGridView1.SelectedCells
            cell.Value = ""
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

note you're enumerating through all the selected cells (look at `For Each cell In...`), which sets `cell` to each selected DataGridViewCell in turn.  That's when you blank out the value.

Your code simply blanked out `CurrentCell` once for every selected cell.  You should brush up on how iterators and `For Each` statements work.

Comment: foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in this.dataGridView1.SelectedCells)
    cell.Value = "";   I was trying to convert that in vb.net.

Comment: @Nihilo it converts fine, no need to change `cell.Value` to `DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value`

Comment: ok this solve my doubt:     For Each DataGridViewCell In DataGridView1.SelectedCells
                DataGridViewCell.Value = ""
            Next

Comment: @Nihilo no. no. no. NO.  `For Each XYZ In ABC` in this line XYZ is a variable you declare.  It can be anything, but it's best to call it something rational, as in the `cell` in my code.  ABC has to be an instance of an object that implements IEnumerable.  That's how it works.  You need to read some basic books.

Answer (score 0):

In your For loop you are not referencing the iteration variable "Cell" - you are only referencing the "CurrentCell" which doesn't change as you iterate.